# How can I show different view for each items of a foreach loop in swiftui?

Tags: swift, swiftui, swiftui-foreach

I want to show different view for different blood groups.

```
let categories = ["A+", "B+", "AB+", "O+", "A-", "B-", "AB-", "O-"]
let onSelectedCategory: (String) -> ()
@State private var selectedCategory: String = ""

var body: some View {
    ScrollView(.horizontal) {
        
        HStack {
            ForEach(categories, id: \.self) { category in
                Button(action: {
                    selectedCategory = category
                    onSelectedCategory(category)
                    //Here I want to go different view for each blood group, 
                    //like APositiveView(), BPositiveView... 
                }, label: {
                    Text(category)
                }).padding(10)
                .foregroundColor(selectedCategory == category ? Color.white: Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.204610765, green: 0.2861392498, blue: 0.3685011268, alpha: 1)))
                .background(selectedCategory == category ? Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.4982050061, green: 0.5490344763, blue: 0.5528618097, alpha: 1)): Color(#colorLiteral(red: 0.9254772663, green: 0.9412199855, blue: 0.9449794888, alpha: 1)))
                .clipShape(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10.0, style: /*@START_MENU_TOKEN@*/.continuous/*@END_MENU_TOKEN@*/))
            }
            
        }
    }
    //.ignoresSafeArea()
}
```

After selecting any blood group it should shows different views for each different blood group like APositiveView(), BPositiveView()

Comment: This isn't a question. What are you asking for? Try to include something with a question mark

Comment: You don't have anything controlling your subviews or which view is showing. You should either be using a `NavigationView`, or a ZStack with @State variables to manage which views to show

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `if` statement within your `HStack` to display the correct view based on the value of `selectedCategory`:

```swift
HStack {
    if selectedCategory == "A+" {
        APositiveView()
    } else if selectedCategory == "B+" {
        BPositiveView()
    } else if ...
    ForEach(categories, id: \.self) { category in
        // ...
    }   
}
```

Though a better way to approach this would be to have a single view that displays such categorical information:

```swift
struct CategoryView: View {
    @Binding var category: String
    var body: some View {
        // Display based on the value of category
    }
}

HStack {
    CategoryView(category: $selectedCategory)
    ForEach(categories, id: \.self) { category in
        // ...
    }
}
```